# Undo a kernel header installation command line

Tags: kernel

Below is what I did:
cd /tmp/

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-wily/linux-headers-4.4.0-040400_4.4.0-040400.201601101930_all.deb

But after all I notice that my problem is not related to linux headers.

Now, how to undo or remove it.

Or if I live my system like that, there will not be any problem?

Comment: Wget just downloads, but doesn't install. Nothing to undo.

Comment: Great! And where does it put it? I'm new in linux environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did was simply download the file:

`linux-headers-4.4.0-040400_4.4.0-040400.201601101930_all.deb`

to the `/tmp` directory.

There is no need to delete it or do anything about it, it will simply be erased on reboot (that's what happens to every file in /tmp, so you know).

If you have any kind of issue, downloading and installing (which seems you didn't, but might have) packages is not a good course of action (specially kernel related packages). Next time you should probably ask about your problem here, or in other forums, before doing something that can compromise your installation or the security of your desktop.

Regards and welcome to Linux.